# Windows 11 not booting after cloning

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-11, clone

I have 2 M.2 drives in my laptop, a 500GB one which is the current OS disk and a new 2TB one, which is where I would like to clone Windows 11 to. I have tried using tools like Samsung Magician and Macrium Reflect Free to clone my OS drive to the new one.

However, when the cloning process is completed and i boot into BIOS, i can only see the Windows Boot Manager on the old disk for some reason.

They are both GPT and I am running out of ideas :/ Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Did you clone the *entire disk* or just one partition?

Comment: The entire disk

Comment: This should have worked. Try to clone again, or try a more Windows-oriented product such as [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/download.html).

Comment: I've done 4 runs in total now, with and without the option to fill excess space in the partitions :/

Comment: No point in repeating it a fifth time - try another cloning product.

Comment: I haven't cloned an OS for a long time, but, I used to image, restore image to new drive (or copy disk to disk) and then make sure the next boot only the new drive was connected. So remove old drive. Is this what you're doing?

Answer (score 1):

The "Windows Boot Manager" option text comes from the UEFI boot variable, which is stored in the BIOS settings NVRAM, and not on the disk at all. So cloning the disk cannot clone it.

Fortunately, Windows installs a second copy of its UEFI boot manager in the standard removable media/fallback path on the EFI System Partition: `\EFI\boot\bootx64.efi`. If you use the BIOS menu to boot from the ESP of the cloned partition, Windows should detect that the "Windows Boot Manager" NVRAM variable for the cloned system disk is missing, and automatically recreate it as a self-healing operation.

Answer (score -1):

Try to copy whole disk with Linux booted from pendrive (use command `dd` or `pv`). When OS i running the copy may be unstable later.

After copy check if the system partition is bootable (has this flag on).

Comment: Please explain why minus.